# Context is updating state but on the second try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
const {auth, setAuth} = useContext(AuthContext);
```

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //axios request to the backend
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/home';
    await axios.post(url, userData)
      .then((res) => {
        let ok = res.data.Authenticated;
        if (ok) {
          setAuth(true);
          setUser(userData);
          console.log("its ok");
        }
        else {
          setAuth(false);
          setUser(null);
          console.log("its not ok");
        }
        console.log(auth, user);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

In the above function, I am trying to update the state of user but at the time, I need to click the button twice to be able to store the user data and authentication in the context states. What is the reason for this?
It is guaranteed that the data is coming from the axios request.

UserContext.js :

```
import {createContext} from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext(null);
```

Auth Context.js :

```
import {createContext} from 'react';
export const AuthContext = createContext(false);
```

Comment: Add the code for how you are calling this `handleSubmit` as well.

Comment: It is being triggered when a form is submitted. The form is of user sign up.

Comment: Then you need to add the e.preventDefault() above your axios call as the first statement inside your `handleSubmit` function .

Comment: Can you show us the main component user and auth states are defined?

Comment: @Shyam That is not working

Comment: @ErfanNaghashlou Included it now.

Comment: Why didn't you use `await` for the Axios request, also for setting your context hooks data to update them asynchronously? As I have no idea about your component structure, I think that might fix the problem.

Comment: @PRAKHARSINGH is that your complete code of your UserContext.js and AuthContext.js ?

Comment: @ErfanNaghashlou I have made the changes now, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Irandoust Yes, The intended action is taking place, but i have to reclick the submit button again in order to print the user data on the console

Comment: What happens after you update user and auth via setUser and setAuth? i mean, which of your components rendering depends on the user being authenticated? The problem is probably from there, you still haven't showed that component

Comment: @ErfanNaghashlou for now, I am just logging and checking if the state is successfully getting updated or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Provider` . Context in react provides 2 things one is the `Provider` and the other is `Consumer` . `useContext` is the hook implementation of Consumer.

Change your contexts as below

UserContext.js

```
import {createContext, useState} from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);

const UserContextProvider = ({ children}) => {

  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default UserContextProvider;
```

AuthContext.js

```
import {createContext, useState} from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext(null);

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children}) => {

  const [ auth, setAuth ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Once you have these Providers . You should wrap your component rendering the Form with these Providers .

```
<UserContextProvider>
  <AuthContextProvider>
    <YourFormComponent /> // your component goes here
  </AuthContextProvider>
</UserContextProvider>
```